# Submakes run the same rule multiple times

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have some software built using parallel multi-level makefiles and I see that when my main Makefile runs two separate targets from a submakefile that have the same dependency, this dependency is run twice simultaneously and an error is created.
Consider the following main *Makefile* in the project root folder:

```
TARGETS = t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8

.PHONY: all $(TARGETS) clean

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): 
    @echo Making $@
    @sleep 1
    $(MAKE) -C folder s$@

clean:
    @echo Making $@
    $(MAKE) -C folder clean
```

and the sub-makefile *folder/Makefile*:

```
SUBTARGETS = st1 st2 st3 st4 st5 st6 st7 st8

$(SUBTARGETS): dep
    @echo Making $@
    @sleep 1
    @touch $@

dep:
    @echo Making $@
    @sleep 1
    @echo bla >> dep

clean:
    rm -f $(SUBTARGETS)
    rm -f dep
    rm -f dep2dump
```

Then running *make -j8* in the root folder will run targets *t1...t8* in parallel, which will then run subtargets *st1...st8*, which all depend on dependency *dep*. From the shell output and the contents of the dep file (8 lines) it is obvious that the *dep* rule is run 8 times, as if the 8 implications of *folder/Makefile* are completely independent.
I thought submakes coordinated when running in parallel and that they would avoid running the same target twice, but it seems this is not the case.
Can anyone suggest a correct way to solve such a case?
If eventually this is an unavoidable weakness of make, what alternative build tools should I look into?
Thanks

EDIT: The answers by MadScientist and Renaud Pacalet are useful but don't exactly solve my problem because they both require that the author of the top-level makefile has knowledge about the internals of the sub-makefile. I have not explained this requirement explicitly in my original post though.

So to give more details, the use case I am trying to solve is that where the source code in path *folder/* is a separate project, eg. a collection of utilities *st1*...*st8* where all (or some) of them have a dependency on library *dep*, internal to the utilities project in *folder*. Then I want to be able to use this sub-project (as seamlessly as possible) in various master projects, each of them using just a (possible different) subset of the utilities *st1*...*st8*. Additionally, the master project may contain many targets *t1*...*t8*, each depending on a different subset of *st1*...*st8*, as shown in my example above. Targets *t1*...*t8* need to be able to run separately, building only the required dependencies from subproject (so *make t1* only builds *st1*, etc), thus having to build all *st1*...*st8* for each one of *t1*...*t8* is not desired. On the other hand they also need to be able to run in parallel, eg. by running *make all*.

Ideally I would not want the author of each master makefile to have to know about internals of sub-project, nor have to include in the sub-makefile all the possible combinations of *st1*...*st8* so that each master project can call just ONE of these to avoid the parallel build issue.

So far I have in mind but not tested the following imperfect solutions:

1. As Renaud suggested, use something like *flock* to at least ensure that the multiple runs of *dep* (by separate sub-make instances) won't happen simultaneously. Cons: requires extra tool (flock or similar) to be installed + *dep* runs multiple times, so extra work is needed to avoid doing the actual compilation over and over again, otherwise just eat the performance cost.
2. Include the sub-makefile in the master makefile so that everything runs in one make instance. This requires makes the sub-makefile able to work regardless of the path of the master makefile that includes it. No big issue. Cons: merging / including two makefile from different authors can open a can of worms, i.e. variables with same name, etc.
3. Modify sub-makefile as described in (2) + In the main project create another makefile, eg. utils.make, that contains a rule for the targets of sub-makefile needed and includes the sub-makefile. So utils.make will be (assuming this master project only needs *st1*, *st5* and *st7*:

```
utils: st1 st5 st7
include foldes/Makefile
```

Then the master makefile will have a *utils-ext* rule as dependency of each of *t1*...*t8* that will be:

```
utils-ext:
$(MAKE) -f rules.make utils
```

to build all the utils needed. This keeps the two main makefiles separate but has all utils / subtargets built when building any single one of *t1*...*t8*, which is suboptimal.

Comment: Submakes coordinate the _total number of jobs running_ so that if you say `-j4` you'll only get a total of 4 jobs running regardless of how many submakes you invoke.  They do not, and cannot, coordinate prerequisite relationships.  Every sub-make is a completely separate process and it has no idea what the other make processes might be building.  It only knows how many things it is building.

Comment: OK, thanks, this make sense given my results. I was/am hoping that there is some mechanism, internal or external to make, that I could use to at least avoid the multiple invocations of dep from running simultaneously. This is what actually breaks my build, I can tolerate multiple runs of dep if done serially, at the expense of more build time, but multiple parallel builds of make are problematic.

Comment: I meant that  multiple parallel builds of *dep* are problematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to move the `dep` dependency to your top Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all $(TARGETS) clean dep

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): dep
    @echo Making $@
    @sleep 1
    $(MAKE) -C folder s$@

dep:
    $(MAKE) -C folder s@
```

Comment: Thank you, I have thought of that but did not do it because I would prefer to keep the sub-makefile self-contained, i.e. solve the problem there and not rely on the root makefile to be polite. I could also add a target all in submakefile depending on st1..8 and make that from the main makefile, instead of each subtarget separately. However, this limits me to only making all st1..8 at once and I cannot choose to build a different set, eg. st1, st5, st7 from the main makefile. Plus, the submakefile remains inherently unsafe if for whatever reason two subtargets are invoked simultaneously.

Comment: @GiannisRoussos Well, in this case you want 2 things: 1) several processes (your submakes) to cooperate with a kind of mutual exclusion to avoid the concurrent build of the common target, 2) several independent make to coordinate such that only one of them builds a common target. For 1) you could use `flock` or something similar. For 2) I have no clue, sorry. But I suspect that this could well be a kind of XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only decent solution to your problem is to have ONE instance of make build all the sub-directory targets you want.  Having the parent make invoke multiple sub-makes in parallel in the same directory, unless every invocation uses a completely disjoint set of targets, is a guaranteed fail situation.  So if you have multiple things you want to do in the submake you should collect them all in one invocation of the sub-make and let the sub-make's parallelism handle it for you.

You could do something like this:

```
TARGETS = t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8

.PHONY: all $(TARGETS) clean

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): .submake ;

.submake:
        $(MAKE) -C folder $(addprefix s,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

Then in the sub-make add this so that when invoked with no arguments it builds everything:

```
all: $(SUBTARGETS)
```

Here, if you run `make` then the sub-make is invoked with no arguments and builds all the things in parallel.  If you invoke `make t1 t2` then the submake is invoked with the arguments `st1 st2`.

Alternatively, you can re-architect your makefiles so that you don't use recursive make at all, and one instance of make knows all the different rules and dependency relationships.